# How to get button pressed effect in Eclipse RCP?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to achieve this effect on an SWT Action (the 2 right most buttons are pressed), as seen in the eclipse console:

[image]

I have a class which extends `org.eclipse.jface.action.Action`. It is added to a `org.eclipse.jface.action.IToolBarManager`.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to use [`IAction.AS_CHECK_BOX`](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jface/action/IAction.html) style:

> Action style constant (value 2) indicating action is a check box (or a toggle button).

So

```
class MyAction extends Action {
    public MyAction() {
        super(NAME, IAction.AS_CHECK_BOX);
    }

    ...
}
```